# Longest increasing subsequence in a linked list of integers

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Given a one-way linked list of integers, I need to return the longest increasing subsequence as a new linked list.
For example, the given list is: 1->5->4->3->6->8->12->10
The new one should be: 3->6->8->12.

I've tried to traverse through the list and compare each node by

```
if (n.data < n.next.data)
  newList.add(n);
```

How can I store the node's and count when the list is in maximum length and then return it?
Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Please add more code, don't let us guess what exactly your tried. BTW: Maybe [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) can help you understand how to best interact with the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: You may also search SO. for example, [start with *java subsequence*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+subsequence)

Comment: I just want to point you to the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68344360/edit) function. Your post has still potential for improvements that may increase the chance of getting an actual answer to concrete problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You should try more, to get an idea of how to approach problems.
Which can be done by on paper / in thought designing how you would have solved the problem.

- You need to maintain a maximum sublist `maxSublist`, and
- a current sublist `currentSublist`.

As you possibly add the current node, you should compare it with the prior node, the last element of the currentSubList. As taking the last element of a single linked list is expensive, I remember the node as `priorNode` after handling it.

In pseudo-code:

```
List<Integer> maxSublist = new SingleLinkedList<>(); // Empty list.

List<Integer> currentSublist = new SingleLinkedList<>();
Node priorNode = null;
for (Node node = list.head(); node != null; node = node.next) {
     if (priorNode == null || node.data > priorNode.data) {
         currentSublist.add(node);
     } else {
         ...
     }
     if (currentSublist.size() > maxSublist.size()) {
         maxSublist = currentSublist;
     }
     priorNode = node;
}
return maxSublist;
```

The above is not the only solution by the way. And you might need to alter the code after filling in `...`.

For the next task try to find a solution this way on your own. Realize what you need: the current sublist and separately the maximum sublist till then.
It is a kind of hard puzzling which brings more pleasure when totaLLy solving it oneself.

Comment: Great start so far, the only thing I (kind of) miss is another three dots in the second `if` block.

Comment: @Wolf Thanks, the OP should use ones skills.